# Showing that $f(x) = \ln x - e^x$ has no real roots

Tags: calculus, functions

> Show that $f(x) = \ln x - e^x$ has no real roots

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = -\infty$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to \infty} e^x \left ( \frac{\ln x}{e^x} - 1 \right ) = -\infty$ I only have to show either that $f(x) \lt 0, \forall x \in (0, +\infty)$ or that $M \lt 0$, where M is the function's local maximum.

However I don't know how to do that, because I cannot solve algebraically $\ln x - e^x \gt 0$ nor $1/x - e^x = 0$.

What are the other ways to finish the proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function is only defined for $x>0$. For such $x$
$$
e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots>x>\log(x)
$$
so $f$ is always negative. In particular, there is no $x>0$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Showing that $\;f(x) = \ln x - e^x\;$ has no real roots is equivalent to showing that there is no real solution to the equation $$\ln x - e^x = 0 \iff \ln x = e^x$$

It can be proven graphically that graphs of $h(x) = \ln x\;$ and $\;g(x) = e^x$, as defined on $x \in \mathbb R_{> 0}$, fail to intersect.

Comment: Well, yes, I plotted the function. But isn't there a pure algebraic method?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to show that $e^{e^x}-x>0$ for every $x>0$. You just use monotonicity.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $e^{x}\ge x+1$ and $\ln x\le x-1$. (These standard inequalities follows from convexity/concavity and a look at suitable tangents of the exponential and logarithm functions.)

Answer (score 1):

$e^{x}$ is an increasing function with $e^{x}>x$. Then $e^{e^{x}}>e^{x}>x=e^{\ln x}$
and consequently $e^{x}>\ln x$.